# aspNetCompatibilityEnabled for just one service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have an asp.net web site.  I only want to use asp.net compatibility mode for one of the wcf services.

However when I do this I end up getting an error message for all of the services because it tries to use it for every one of them.

How can I selectively use aspNetCompatibilityEnabled for wcf.

I am doing this because of performance issues.

Comment: You need to give more detail on how you have your services set up and configured in IIS (for example, are they all using the same AppPool) to get a meaning answer.

Comment: They all use the same application pool

Comment: Then you'll need to to set up your services like @ServiceGuy recommends. Since each AppPool is a single root AppDomain then the AspNetCompatibilityEnabled applies to all IIS web sites or applications sharing the same AppPool.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: That's not quite right. An IIS AppPool is a _pool_ of AppDomains, one for each IIS Application that uses that pool. Hence, the AspNetCompatibility setting is per application, not per AppPool!

Comment: @ServiceGuy: Yes, each AppPool can contain multiple AppDomains (I guess root was confusing word to use). Each AppPool runs under its own w3wp.exe worker process and all AppDomains in it share that configuration (same framework version and such). Maybe a better way of saying it is that the ASP.NET configuration within each w3wp.exe process is shared across AppDomains and what affects one affect all.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: No, sorry, still not right. The most important scope of execution in .Net is an AppDomain. In IIS, you have one Web.config per application, not per application pool, right? And even if multiple apps share one AppPool, they all have their own (isolated) configuration. Same is true for static class members. So, within one AppPool, you can have one app with AspNetCompatibility enabled, and another without, etc... (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx)

Comment: When I have some time next week I'll try setting different IIS applications within a single IIS web site and the same AppPool to have different AspNetCompatibility settings enabled. I don't believe that will work but I'll find out one way or the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. `ServiceHostingEnvironment.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled` is a static member, hence it always applies to all services within one AppDomain.

If you definitely don't want AspNetCompatibility enabled for some services they have to be hosted in a different (IIS) app. Could still be within the same site, though! Would that work for your scenario?

Comment: It is not ideal because I would have to modifier our installer